# For /r in batch file suddenly adding a period to file path

Tags: batch-file

I was editing some batch files that use doff.exe to set a date variable, then search through the subfolders of a folder named for the date to find a particular file, copy it, rename it, then process it.  All of a sudden, without changing the way it was written, the for /r loop is adding a period to the file path.  So, after using doff and navigating to the date-named directory this is my code:

> for /r %%d in (.) do copy %%d\FILE.TXT Y:\Folder\subfolder\other_folder\

It used to output this:

```
X:\Stuff\other_stuff\20180314>copy X:\Stuff\Other_stuff\20180314\FILE.TXT Y:\Folder\subfolder\other_folder 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

until it found the file, then it would copy it.  Now, instead, it returns this (note the extra .\ in front of the filename):

```
X:\Stuff\other_stuff\20180314>copy X:\Stuff\Other_stuff\20180314\.\FILE.TXT Y:\Folder\subfolder\other_folder

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And never finds the file, because of the extra .\ in the file path.  I haven't changed anything that I know of, we use this code string in tons of places, I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.  In case it's relevant, here's the full script to that point:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('doff yyyymmdd') do (
set mm2=%%a
set dd2=%%b
set yyyy2=%%c)

X:
cd Stuff
cd Other_stuff
cd %mm2%

for /r %%d in (.) do copy %%d\FILE.TXT Y:\Folder\subfolder\other_folder\
```

Comment: I bet if you read the help file for the `FOR` command you will see why. The output you are experiencing has always done that when using that specific code.  So essentially what I am saying is your assumption is incorrect.  It has always output the period.

Comment: Maybe I need someone to explain it to me like I'm five, because I've read this like ten times now, and it seems like it should be doing exactly what I expect it to (and exactly what it does in all the other instances we use it):  
    "Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
    statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
    specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
    assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
    will just enumerate the directory tree."

Comment: Yes, that is what the help of `for /R` says. But there is and always was `\.` appended, which does not disturb though, as `.` means the current directory...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no command usually changes its behaviour all of a sudden without having changed anything. I can assure you `for` does not change just like that.

Furthermore, an additional `.` in a file path does not harm at all, because `.` just means the current directory. Therefore `D:\a\b\c.ext` points to the same target as `D:\a\.\b\.\c.ext`.
(Just for the sake of completeness, there is also `..` which points to the parent directory, so it goes one level up, hence `D:\a\b\c.ext` points to the same item as `D:\a\b\d\..\c.ext`.)

Anyway, to understand what is happening and where the extra `.` comes from, you need to know that the [`for` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) (without and with the [`/R` option](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)) does not access the file system always but only when needed.

The plain `for` command accesses the file system only when at least a [wildcard](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) like `*` or `?` is used in the set (the set is the part in between the parentheses following the loop variable reference; type `for /?`). You can easily confirm that with the following code snippet typed into a command prompt window (to use this in a batch file, double the `%`-signs):

```cmd
>>> rem /* List all `*.txt` and `*.bin` files in current directory;
>>> rem    the example output below lists two files: */
>>> for %I in (*.txt *.bin) do @echo %I
sample.txt
data.bin

>>> rem // Print all items even if there are no such files:
>>> for %I in (just/text no/file) do @echo %I
just/text
no/file
```

The first `for` loop returns existing files only, so the file system needs to be accessed. The second loop just returns the given items without accessing the file system. Both items contain a character (`/`) that is not allowed in file names, so there cannot exist such files.

For the set of `for /R` (that is again the part in between `()`) it is exactly the same. However, to retrieve the recursive directory tree, the file system has to be accessed of course. So check out the following code snippet (given the current directory is `C:\Test` that contains 3 sub-directories):

```cmd
>>> rem /* List all `*.txt` and `*.bin` files in current directory tree;
>>> rem    the example output below lists some files: */
>>> for /R %I in (*.txt *.bin) do @echo %I
C:\Test\sample.txt
C:\Test\sub1\any.bin
C:\Test\sub1\data.bin
C:\Test\sub2\text.txt

>>> rem // Print all items even if there are no such files:
>>> for /R %I in (just/text no/file) do @echo %I
C:\Test\just/text
C:\Test\no/file
C:\Test\sub1\just/text
C:\Test\sub1\no/file
C:\Test\sub2\just/text
C:\Test\sub2\no/file
C:\Test\sub3\just/text
C:\Test\sub3\no/file
```

As you can see in the first example the file system is accessed and only matching files are returned. In the second example, the directory tree is retrieved from the file system, but the items in the set are just appended and not checked against the file system.

The `.` is nothing special to `for` or `for /R`, it is just a string without a wildcard, so the files system is not checked. Therefore in our test scenario the output would be:

```cmd
>>> rem // `.` is the only character in the set:
>>> for /R %I in (.) do @echo %I
C:\Test\.
C:\Test\sub1\.
C:\Test\sub2\.
C:\Test\sub3\.
```

I hope this explains the behaviour you are facing!

Just for the sake of completeness:
If you want to get rid of the appended `.` for cosmetic reasons, nest another (standard) `for` loop and use the [`~f` modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

```cmd
>>> rem // `.` is the only character in the set:
>>> for /R %I in (.) do @for &J in (%I) do echo %~fI
C:\Test
C:\Test\sub1
C:\Test\sub2
C:\Test\sub3
```

Answer (score 0):

The trailing period has **always** displayed when a single period is used for the set when using `FOR /R`. If you want to get rid of it then do this:

```
for /r %%G in (.) do copy %%~fG\FILE.TXT Y:\Folder\subfolder\other_folder\
```