# How can I search for files recursively but only operate on instances where the file is found using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, automation

The objective of my script is to search for a single filename (of which there are  files of that name existing in different folders) recursively given a starting path and output the path of each file found excluding name and extension.

I've been stuck on this all morning for some reason. I have produced the below code.

```
@echo off

for /r D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients %%x in (EnterpriseSettings.config) do (
    echo %%~nxx
    echo %%~dpx
)
```

I was under the impression from other people's answers and documentation that this will only execute the commands in the 'do' clause if a file within the parentheses is found. However, when executing and piping into a file I have a ridiculous amount of unnecessary lines as it is outputting the directory it is in even when it hasn't found the file. I am confused by this as I thought the whole point of specifying a set was the at the commands in do would only execute  in an instance where it finds the filename.

```
D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients\Example\
D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients\Example\Example\
D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients\Example\Example\Config\
D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients\Example\Example\Config\Stage\
```

Could anyone elighten me as to how I've mis-interpreted the usage of the for-loop or syntax?

Comment: Would you not simply migrate this into `Powershell` since PS has more control over the `FileSystem`. Is there a specific reason to run `batch`?

Comment: @Alex I hadn't considered that, as I don't need to do this multiple times and this is actually a small component of a larger task. I am trying to use Microsoft's TFS CLU to edit and checkout files programmatically, these paths will be the ones I resolve to TFS mappings. I was under the impression that this was fairly trivial to do in a batch file. :) I need to do it in batch as this snippet will be inside a batch script for automating some source control stuff.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I want the directory to be output, but only when the file is in there. Which is what I thought the whole point of in () do was?

D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients\Example\Example\Config\Stage\ 

is the correct path. The others before were it traversing down to that one?

Comment: Using `EnterpriseSettings*.config` probably solves the problem, but might include false positives.

Comment: @ThomasWeller why is this? Why was the do running when the file hadn't been found?

Comment: At least it does not seem to be a bug. It's known for a longer time: https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html Also note that that site says "must use a wildcard". It would be interesting to see the help text of older OS or even DOS.

Comment: [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and [`for /R`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) need wildcards to actually access the file system and search for matching files; but the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) does not need wildcards, so you could do: `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%X in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients\EnterpriseSettings.config"') do echo(%%~nxX& echo(%%~dpX.`

Comment: @ThomasWeller that has solved my problem. I used the ? wildcard mentioned in that documentation and I am now getting consistent results. Thanks.

Comment: Take also a look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49295770)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems more obvious to me to do this with a `DIR` command. See the meaning of `/A:-D-S-L` in the output of the `DIR /?` command.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D-S-L "D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients\EnterpriseSettings.config"') DO (
    echo "%%~nxx"
    echo "%%~dpx"
)
```

Comment: @aschipfl - Thank you. I agree. I have made the change, and a little more.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is more than likely because `For /R`, *(and `For /D`)*, expect a wildcard pattern.

This can be fixed by:

- using the `*` wildcard, `("EnterpriseSettings.conf*g")`
- using the `?` wldcard `("EnterpriseSettings.c?nfig")`
  *It must be noted however that there is a potential that non required files could be matched too, even with careful placement of the wildcard.*
- use a different method, such as the `Dir` or `Where` commands with their recursive options.
  *This should match only exact filenames, example below*.

---

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "dirBase=D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients"
Set "fileName=EnterpriseSettings.config"

If /I Not "%__CD__%"=="%dirBase%\" (
    PushD "%dirBase%" 2>Nul && (Set "_=$") || Exit /B
)

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-S-L "%fileName%" 2^>Nul') Do Echo %%~dpA
Pause

If "%_%"=="$" PopD
EndLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

As already shown by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50720263), using the `dir` command is a good solution, which I would prefer.

An alternative way is to use `for /R` as you already do, but to add `if exist`, like this:

```cmd
for /R "D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients" %%x in ("EnterpriseSettings.config") do (
    if exist "%%~x" if not exist "%%~x\" (
        echo %%~nxx
        echo %%~dpx
    )
)
```

The `if not exist` part with the item plus trailing `\` excludes directories with matching names.

Another way is to add a wildcard (`?` in this example) to force `for` to access the file system and to check for matching files, but to filter the result against false positives:

```cmd
for /R "D:\Workspaces\fwarrener-lglesias\Example\Example\Clients" %%x in ("EnterpriseSettings?.config") do (
    if /I "%%~nxx"=="EnterpriseSettings.config" (
        echo %%~nxx
        echo %%~dpx
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have revamped my batch script.

Tell me if this helps you in any way:

---

```
@ECHO OFF

SET path=C:\Users\<USER>\<DIRS>
SET filename=EnterpriseSettings*.config

For /R %path% %%f in (%filename%) do (
    echo %%~pf
)

PAUSE
```

I also used `~p` idiom which is `Extract the path only` found at: [Filename parsing in batch file and more idioms](http://www.rgagnon.com/gp/gp-0008.html)

Comment: You do not explain what the problem of OP was, where his mistake is. You do not consider OP's requirements. He does not only want to list the files, he works with them (see `%%~nxx`), which is not possible with `dir`. That's not possible with your solution.

Comment: Alex, this works really well to list files and is a great solution but doesn't fit into the other code I have as I will need to operate on each path as it's found. I've up-voted as this was useful in getting all the paths and could be worked around, however I am looking for how this should've been done using for-loop.

Comment: @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias, if you have existing code and wish solutions you can integrate with it, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50718961/edit) to include that code. _Don't expect responders to give their time and expertise providing answers which do not meed your hidden requirements_. Your provided question only `echo`es the name with extension and the drive with path!

Comment: @Compo: which is exactly what a [MCVE] is supposed to do: write as little code as possible to demonstrate the problem without adding too many details on the rest of the requirements.

Comment: @Compo Alex asked me why I was doing this in batch in a comment and I explained that I wanted to resolve the found files to TFS mappings, hence why i was doing a loop as I wanted to do that as each file was found. You're implying that it is because of 'hidden details' that this question doesn't apply. But I asked for how to execute a command when the file is found in the loop and I asked that for a reason. The echo's were just there for debugging purposes to explain the issue I was having. My objective was to resolve the paths not to output them.

Comment: I misinterpreted the question and currently working on a solution.

Comment: @Compo I refused to make it as accepted because it doesn't explain why my for logic is acting the way it is, which was my question. Solving that question and getting the for logic working makes the code compatible with my other code... I asked a clear question and Alex has said that he misinterpreted it. I up-voted him and let him know that his answer is useful in a way, as I can take that quickly generated list of paths and add them to our documentation.

Comment: @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias check the new code. I tested it by putting many config files in different folders and recursively searching the root directory. The script returned all paths without filenames where the `config` file was found. :)